# Add a single attribute to a model's Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in one of my controllers;

```
render :json => Article.order("ID Desc").limit(3)
```

Which outputs an array of articles like:

```
[{"id":1, "content":"Blah"},{"id":2, "content":"Blah"}, {"id":3, "content":"Blah"}]
```

All I want to do is add a `count` attribute to each model. So it would be something like:

```
[{"id":1, "content":"Blah", "count":3},{"id":2, "content":"Blah", "count":1}, {"id":3, "content":"Blah", "count":6}]
```

Is there anyway to go about this in my controller without overriding the `as_json` method?

I saw a `merge` method called in another question, so I tried this:

```
render :json => Article.order("ID Desc").limit(3).merge(:count => 2)
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better for you to handle this json yourself, but not `to_json` method( of Arrays or active_record)

```
articles = Article.order("ID Desc").limit(3)
render :json => articles.map { |article|  
  {
    :id => article.id,
    :content => article.content, 
    :count => 3 # or 2 or 1
  }
}
```